# Does order matter? Adding an AlternateView to MailMessage.AlternateViews

Tags: email, .net-4.5, mime

I vaguely recall reading -somewhere- that the order in which an `AlternateView` is added to the `MailMessage.AlternateViews` collection matters when determining which `AlternateView` should be displayed. I recall it being based on the ability to display the message and, if the device doesn't support HTML for example, fallback to HTML. Unfortunately, I can't find the original article nor any other article mentioning how this should work.

Does the order in which an `AlternateView` gets added to the `MailMessage.AlternateViews` collection matter? If so, how does it work? Any documentation?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov How is MIME not a relevant tag? The MailMessage.AlternateViews is a list of MIME multipart/alternative - and the answer to the question is specified in the RFC for MIME.

Answer (score 4):

The order is important, according to [RFC1521 - MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521).

> In general, user agents that compose multipart/alternative entities
> must place the body parts in increasing order of preference, that is,
> with the preferred format last

MailMessage.Attachments does use the order you add them in - so make sure the views are added to that collection in the correct order, with lowest priority first and the preferred (probably `text/html`) view last.

Comment: Upvoted as factual.  However there's a catch if you're targeting Outlook users.  Microsoft have decided to go against this in favour of their own proprietary standard.  In this case the HTML view must be first in the views as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734403/send-email-to-outlook-with-ics-meeting-appointment